# Not able to pick the Date in samsung galaxy s7 tab using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, datepicker, browserstack

I am automating the web based application for desktop and mobile devices. I am using browserstack to run the test cases on different devices/browsers.
I am using selenium webdriver with java for automation.
In one of the scenario, I want to select a date from calendar, for desktop browser sendkeys is working however for samsung galaxy tab s7 sendkeys is not working. When I click on the calendar it opens up like below given screenshot. I am not able to locate the date/month or set button of the calendar.

Code working for Desktop -
enterDetails(findTextBox("Date of Birth"), "01/01/2002");

[image]